# Line integral of a continuous vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

I'm studying line integrals of vector fields and I can't do this prove:

Let $\gamma : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ a regular parameterized curve e $F$
a continuous vector field defined over the image of $\gamma,\: C=\gamma([a,b])$, with values in $\mathbb{R}^m$. So, the line integral of $F$ over $\gamma$ is given by the formula:

$$\int_\gamma F \cdot d\vec{r} = \int_b^a F(\gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma ' (t)dt$$

I'm trying but i can't understand this $d \vec{r}$:

Can someone help me? I would be very grateful.

Comment: What is your definition of the left hand side?

Comment: I suppose that $d\vec r$ is a vector tangent to the line at a point $\gamma(t)$.  Is It true?

Comment: The meaning of $\mathrm{d}\vec r$ is the "infinitesimal step in the direction (hence $\vec r$) of the curve $\gamma$". That, however, is informal. The way to formally capture the notion of integrating in the direction of something (note: $F\color{red}{\cdot}\mathrm{d}\vec r$, the dot product representing how much $F$ points in the direction of the curve $\gamma$) is either with a Riemannian limit, or by just using the right hand side. That's what Arctic Char meant; this is really about the definition. The LHS is defined to be equal to the RHS.

Comment: Another way to look at it: the integral is $$\oint_\gamma F(r)\cdot\mathrm{d}\vec r=\oint_\gamma F(r=\gamma(t))\cdot\mathrm{d}\vec(r=\gamma(t))$$And we define $\mathrm{d}(\gamma(t))=\gamma'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$ as you'd expect

Comment: @FShrike Thanks, Thank you, you have helped me a lot.